# Android Null Pointer Exception on collectAsStateWithLifecycle() in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I have a ViewModel like this:

```
class LocalVM @Inject constructor(
private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle){

    val transaction: StateFlow<TransactionUiState> =
        savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("transaction", TransactionUiState(isLoading = true))

    fun fetchDetails(id: String) {
        // API call to fetch transaction
        updateTransaction(transaction)
    }

    fun updateTransaction(transaction: Transaction){
        savedStateHandle["transaction"] = TransactionUiState(transaction)
    }
}
@Parcelize
data class TransactionUiState(
    var isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val payerName: String = "-") : Parcelable
```

And in my Compose fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        viewModel.fetchDetails(args.id)
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        
  setViewCompositionStrategy(
    ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                TransactionDetailsScreen(
                    loader = viewModel.loaderState,
                    transactionFlow = viewModel.transaction.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
                )
            }
        }
    }

@Composable
private fun TransactionDetailsScreen(
    loader: StateFlow<Boolean>,
    transactionFlow: State<TransactionUiState>,
) {
    //>>>> WITHOUT THIS IF CONDITION MY APP CRASHES<<<<<
    if (transactionFlow.value is TransactionUiState) { 
        MaterialTheme {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .background(white)
            ) {
                Text(transactionFlow.value.payerName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my TransactionDetailsScreen() composible if I don't have the

```
if (transactionFlow.value is TransactionUiState) {
```

my app will crash with null pointer exception. It is very weird. Even android studio is warning me with a Useless check. I have to use @Suppress("USELESS_IS_CHECK")

Why is this happening? Is this a known issue? Or am I doing something wrong here?